# For loop with exponent optimization in matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop, optimization, vectorization

i'm calculating the planar antenna array pattern, the problem is that it takes ~10s to calculate the pattern, and i need to calculate it a lot of times in my algorithm. The majority of time is spent to calculate the for loop. Please advise me how can i reduce the for loop execution time, or replace it with some other solution. Thanks in advance.

```
clc; close all; clear all;
Nx=32; Ny=32;
betta_n = zeros(Nx,Ny); lambda=1;
dx = [1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 ];
dy = [1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 ];
a_n = ones(Nx, Ny);
dtetta = 0.01;
dphi = 0.01;
tetta0 = -pi/2:dtetta:pi/2;
phi0 = dphi:dphi:2*pi;
[phi, tetta] = meshgrid(phi0,tetta0);
j = sqrt(-1);
amp_phase=a_n.*(cos(betta_n)+j*sin(betta_n));
sinU=sin(tetta).*cos(phi);
sinV=sin(tetta).*sin(phi);
%     AF_Field = 0;
AF_Field = zeros(length(tetta0),length(phi0));
tic
for n=1:Nx-1
    for m=1:Ny-1
        AF_Field = amp_phase(n,m)*exp(j*2*pi*(n-1)/lambda*dx(n)*(sinU)).*exp(j*2*pi*(m-1)/lambda*dy(m)*(sinV)) + AF_Field;  
    end
end
toc
```

Comment: Lookup tables might help here...Also make j*2*pi a constant and calc before the loop...  Lookup tables for your SIN and COS calcs would make a big difference

Comment: Thanks for your help, could you please elaborate about the lookup tables, the sinU and sinV are 315x628 matrices, how can i use LUTs instead of them in the loop?

Comment: Only within your loop, IF sin or cos are being calculated inside the loop (or in a function that is inside the loop), these could be very slow.  315 * 628 is a small cache, but perhaps not the cache (lookup) that is required.  does amp_phase calc sin and cos values in the loop?  Consider pre-calc ing all the sin and cos values and storing them in arrays and using the array values inside the loops